# Find next id from varchar in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a row that is a varchar(50) that has a unique constraint and i would like to get the next unique number for an new insert but with a given prefix.

My rows could look like this:

```
ID (varchar)
00010001
00010002
00010003
00080001
```

So if I would like to get the next unqiue number from the prefix "0001" it would be "00010004" but if I would want it for the prefix "0008" it would be "00080002".

There will be more then 1 millon entries in this table. Is there a way with Oracle 11 to perform this kind of operation that is fairly fast?

I know that this setup is totaly insane but this is what I have to work with. I cant create any new tables etc.

Comment: Setup is really insane, is there any possibility to work on this with different language or it must be pure plSQL.

Comment: We have a persistance layer using Hibernate so HQL and Java is possible to use

Comment: Does there REALLY have to be no gaps?  If not then you could use a sequence and accept that the next number could be `00080004`.  That would of course limit you on the number of available numbers

Comment: @HughJones there can be gaps but its not preferable. So as few gaps as possible is what I aim for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for the max value of the specified prefix and increment it:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT '00010001' id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3     SELECT '00010002' id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4     SELECT '00010003' id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5     SELECT '00080001' id FROM DUAL
  6  )
  7  SELECT :prefix || to_char(MAX(to_number(substr(id, 5)))+1, 'fm0000') nextval
  8    FROM DATA
  9   WHERE ID LIKE :prefix || '%';

NEXTVAL
---------
00010004
```

I'm sure you're aware that this is an inefficient method to generate a primary key. Furthermore it won't play nicely in a multi-user environment and thus won't scale. Concurrent inserts will wait then fail since there is a UNIQUE constraint on the column.

If the prefix is always the same length, you can reduce the workload somewhat: you could create a specialized index that would find the max value in a minimum number of steps:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_fetch_max ON your_table (substr(id, 1, 4), 
                                         substr(id, 5) DESC);
```

Then the following query could use the index and will stop at the first row retrieved:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM (SELECT substr(id, 1, 4) || substr(id, 5) id
          FROM your_table
         WHERE substr(id, 1, 4) = :prefix
         ORDER BY substr(id, 5) DESC)
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

If you need to do simultaneous inserts with the same prefix, I suggest you use [`DBMS_LOCK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_lock.htm#sthref5367) to request a lock on the specified `newID`. If the call fails because someone is already inserting this value, try with `newID+1`. Although this involves more work than traditional sequence, at least your inserts won't wait on each others (potentially leading to deadlocks).

Comment: If the prefix isn't always the same length but the incrementing part is always 4 chars/digits, you could use `substr(id, 1, length(id) - 4), substr(id, -4)`. Which makes the query even more complicated of course.

Comment: SQL Fiddles of that for [prefix `0008`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19ca6/3) and [prefix `10`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19ca6/4). Just for fun.

Comment: +1 for a great answer: I'd be tempted to make the indexes more compact by converting the substring() results to numbers. Seems like a good use for virtual columns if available in the version in use.

Comment: I think this will be my approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very unsatisfactory situation for you.  As other posters have pointed out - if you don't use sequences then you will almost certainly have concurrency issues.  I mentioned in a comment the possibility that you live with big gaps. This is the simplest solution but you will run out of numbers after 9999 inserts.

Perhaps an alternative would be to create a separate sequence for each prefix.  This would only really be practical if the number of prefixes is fairly low but it could be done.

ps - your requirement that > 1000000 records should be possible may, in fact, mean you have no choice but to redesign the database.

Comment: Concurrency depends on how the OP is planning to use the table. If it's in a batch job this may not be an issue, if it's for ad-hoc report generating it may not be an issue either.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT to_char(to_number(max(id)) + 1, '00000000')
FROM mytable
WHERE id LIKE '0001%'
```

SQLFiddle demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f543/5/0

Comment: What if after `SELECT` someone just inserts another row with the last `id` greater than the one returned by `SELECT`?

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev - is this in his requirements? If this is a problem he's obviously going to need to lock the records somehow.

Comment: Probably even the entire table.